# Prototype apply loses my scope

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, scope, apply

I am calling function which return result to callback(this is old library) by using prototype `apply`. But after this I'am losing my `this` scope in the callback.

```
export default {
CONSTANCT: 123,

x () {
    var arr = [1, 2, this.yCallback]
    this.y.apply(this, arr) //trying give null instead this, but now works too
},

y (a, b, callback) {
    var c = a + b

    callback(c)
},

yCallback (result) {
    console.log(result)
    console.log(this.CONSTANCT)
}
```

}

in `yCallback` function `this` - `undefined`

Changing string `callback(c)` to `callback.apply(this, [c])` resolve the problem. But i really want to avoid library fixes

Comment: `this.yCallback.bind(this)`

Comment: @Li357 apply will call it there and then, bind will bind `this` to the function.

Comment: @Keith My bad, I misread. To OP: `this` is lost when you do `callback(c)`. You aren't calling `callback` from an object thus no 'context'. Bind `yCallback`.